# Is there any way to create in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, foreach, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
        var json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\sira.json");
        dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        Arac.adli_tip = x.adli_tip;
        Arac.aile_hukuku = x.aile_hukuku;
        Arac.avrupa_birligi_hukuku = x.avrupa_birligi_hukuku;
        Arac.bankacilik_hukuku = x.bankacilik_hukuku;
        Arac.bilisim_hukuku = x.bilisim_hukuku;
        Arac.borclar_hukuku = x.borclar_hukuku;
        Arac.cevre_hukuku = x.cevre_hukuku;
        Arac.deniz_ticareti_hukuku = x.deniz_ticareti_hukuku;
        Arac.devletler_ozel_hukuku = x.devletler_ozel_hukuku;
        Arac.esya_hukuk = x.esya_hukuk;
         .
         .
         .
```

`sira.json` is a configuration file about my winforms app.
Here is content of `sira.json` file:

```
{
  "adli_tip": 15,
  "aile_hukuku": 43,
  "avrupa_birligi_hukuku": 22,
  "bankacilik_hukuku": 10,
  .
  .
  .
  "vergi_hukuku": 3
}
```

I want to get some values from file and set static variables. But these config variables nearly 60. 
Is there any way to set static variables programmatically, for example with `forecach` or `while`?

**EDIT:** @subi_speedrunner comment and @T.J.Crowder reply, I searched about `Reflection` and I coded like this:
[image]

But it gives an error. I did not understand why?

Comment: May be you can use `foreach` with the condition being 'foreach properties of Arac' , initialize the fields.

Comment: 60 isn't that bad.. considering the performance loss if you were to use reflection to populate each properties dynamically.

Comment: @RosdiKasim: .Net's reflection is very, very fast in any of the last few framework releases. Compared with the cost of reading the file, 60 of these is nothing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Really?.. I was always told to avoid reflection if possible.. hmm.. perhaps I will do a little benchmark later..

Comment: @RosdiKasim: There's a cost, it's just (again) relative to *reading a file*, it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Rosdi Kasim. Who cares? this code will only run one time. Performance is not a concern here.

Comment: @Rosdi Kasim. Any way, if you want to improve performance but at the same time keep being dynamic you can use this small library I wrote:  https://github.com/jesuslpm/FastDynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Arac` property names match exactly to `json` property names and `Arac` properties are `public static` properties, the following code will work:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public static class Arac
    {
        public static int adli_tip { get; set; }
        public static int aile_hukuku { get; set; }
        public static int avrupa_birligi_hukuku { get; set; }
        public static int bankacilik_hukuku { get; set; }


        public static string string_value {get; set;}
        public static DateTime date_value { get; set; }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"
{
  ""adli_tip"": 15,
  ""aile_hukuku"": 43,
  ""avrupa_birligi_hukuku"": 22,
  ""bankacilik_hukuku"": 10,

""string_value"": ""some value"",
""date_value"": ""2016-01-24 11:18:00""
}";
            JObject arac = JObject.Parse(json);
            foreach (var prop in typeof(Arac).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                var token = arac.GetValue(prop.Name);
                if (token != null)
                { 
                    object value = token.ToObject(prop.PropertyType);
                    prop.SetValue(null, value, null);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("adli_tip {0}", Arac.adli_tip);
            Console.WriteLine("aile_hukuku {0}", Arac.aile_hukuku);
            Console.WriteLine("avrupa_birligi_hukuku {0}", Arac.avrupa_birligi_hukuku);
            Console.WriteLine("bankacilik_hukuku {0}", Arac.bankacilik_hukuku);
            Console.WriteLine("string_value {0}", Arac.string_value);
            Console.WriteLine("date_value {0}", Arac.date_value);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I use `JObject` directly instead of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, this is because `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>` actually returns a `JObject`, and I prefer all features of `JObject` than working with a generic `dynamic` object.

The code works with integer properties as well as other type of properties as you can see on the sample code.

The following is the relevant code:

```
JObject arac = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var prop in typeof(Arac).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static |  BindingFlags.Public))
{
    var token = arac.GetValue(prop.Name);
    if (token != null)
    { 
        object value = token.ToObject(prop.PropertyType);
        prop.SetValue(null, value, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support sir. But I got an error in your code. Here is the screenshot: http://imgur.com/YJ0tPA0 May be, is there a problem in my IDE?

Comment: Now, I am trying code on Console, everything is Ok. But when I try WinForms, I get error.I did not understand why it is.

Comment: Change id to prop.SetValue(null, value, null). The SetValue overload which takes two arguments is a recent addition to .NET Framework. Because you are targeting an older .NET fx version, this overload is not available.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use reflection, defined in the [`System.Reflection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481557(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. Rough sketch:

- Get the `Type` objects for `Arac` and `x`
- Have an array of the field names you want to process, or use `Type` object for `Arac`'s [`GetProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [`GetFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to get an array of all of its properties/fields (you can specify various features, like whether you only want public ones, etc.)
- Loop through the array or the list and for each field:

  - If you don't already have a `FieldInfo`/`PropertyInfo` object from `Arac`'s `Type` object, use [`Type#GetField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Type#GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) (or one of their relatives) to get it
  - Get the `FieldInfo`/`PropertyInfo` for `x`'s `Type` object for the same field/property
  - Use the `GetValue` method(s) of the `FieldInfo`/`PropertyInfo` you got from `x`'s type object to read the value, and the `SetValue` method(s) of the other `FieldInfo`/`PropertyInfo` object to write the value to `Arac`

Not necessarily saying it's a good idea, since as soon as you put those field names into strings, you make it harder to refactor them with tools, etc., but if the question is "Can I do this?" the answer is "Yes" (and sometimes it's a reasonable choice, there are just trade-offs).

Comment: Thank you sir. I am not a senior of C#. I will learn `System.Reflection`, and  `Arac`. After this, I will leave a comment. Kind regards.